# Ordinal correlation vs. univariate isotonic regression - practical differences?

Tags: ordinal-data, isotonic

Ordinal correlation statistics such as Spearman's $\rho$ or Kendall's $\tau$ allow us to measure the association of two variables while considering only the ranks of the observations.

[Isotonic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotonic_regression) allows us to fit a free-form non-decreasing function from our regression predictions to the data. When we have more than one predictor, isotonic regression can go beyond ordinal correlation since it allows us to combine multiple predictors to fit ordinal data optimally.

I'm concerned with the case of a single predictor. Does fitting an isotonic regression and using the resulting goodness-of-fit as an association statistic offer any advantage over ordinal correlation coefficients? Or does it measure the same thing that Spearman's $\rho$ measures?